# Was my question closed for the wrong reason?

Tags: discussion

[How can I smoothly rotate a joint to an angle?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/66903/how-can-i-smoothly-rotate-a-joint-to-an-angle)

Maybe I should have been more clear, I was asking what torque to apply (each tick) to a joint to achieve a rotation to a specific angle. (Using Box2d)

I think they interpreted my question as "how do I interpolate between two different angles".

Answer (score 2):

I can see how one might interpret that as a duplicate.

If the linked duplicate does not address your question, just edit your question to include the clarifying details necessary to disambiguate it. In this case, those details would at least include what you just mentioned, that you were "asking what torque to apply (each tick) to a joint to achieve a rotation to a specific angle," rather than how to interpolate the rotation angle.

Editing the question will place it into the re-open queue for review and handling.